# Block setting default value for not provided properties in post controller models in .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to disabled default? feature of web api. Currently I have post method in api controller with class as input:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyMethod(MyClass class)

public class MyClass
{
   public bool FirstProp {get;set;}
   public decimal SecondProp {get;set;}
}
```

that contains bool and decimal required values. When I send json with this values as null, my api behaves ok, it throws exception that value is invalid for specified column.

The problem is when I don't send this column (example json: `{ }`) and I get in controller method class with default values (in my case false for FirstProp type and 0 for SecondProp type). What is the best way to block this kind of serialization/mapping for my post method controller ?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I don't send this column (example json: `{ }`)

For you do not pass any property,an easier way is to make field `required`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool FirstProp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public decimal SecondProp { get; set; }
}
```

For asp.net core 3.x,you need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and add NewtonsoftJson support like below:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443810/11398810