# Serializing property with dynamic name and Required annotation

Tags: c#, json, serialization, openapi, system.text.json

I have a class that is used for collection responses:

```cs
public class CollectionResponse<T>
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Items { get; } = new(1);

    public CollectionResponse(string name, IEnumerable<T> objects)
    {
        Items.Add(name, objects);
    }
}
```

`[JsonExtensionData]` perfectly helps with having a dynamic name for different response types. However, I need to set `[Required]` annotation for that extended data to reflect it in OpenApi schema.

```cs
new CollectionResponse<Car>("cars", new [] {new Car()});
```

should result in OpenApi schema:

```
"CarCollectionResponse": {
        "required": [
          "cars"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "cars": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Car"
            },
            "readOnly": true
          }
        }
      }
```

So, question is, how to maintain a dynamic property name while also setting it as `[Required]`?

Comment: It looks like you are using System.Text.Json.  This serializer does not support `[Required]` annotations, see [Compare Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json, and migrate to System.Text.Json: Required properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#required-properties) and [Does the new `System.Text.Json` have a required property attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58443181) for confirmation.  The suggested workaround is to manually check for the required property in a converter, and throw an exception if not present.

Comment: Also, can you please explain what you mean by *However, I need to set `[Required]` annotation for that extended data*?  Extension data is by definition free-form.  There are no properties to which to apply annotations.  Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing what you want to do?

Comment: Instead of posting the code that hard to read , it is better for you to post a Json you have and a json you need.

Comment: Thanks guys for quick comments, specified my question with more focusing on my required result rather than `thoughts`

Comment: I suspect there is no way to do what you want automatically, because the schema is generated from compile-time attributes and, in your example, the property name `"cars"` is entirely runtime.  And, of course, a `Dictionary<string, object>` has no compile-time type information from which to generate a schema for its values.

Comment: Why are you even using an untyped data model like `public Dictionary<string, object> Items`?  If you used a fully typed data model (E.g. `public class CarResponse { [Required] public List<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new (); }`) the schema would be generated automatically.